# VMWare Ubuntu low graphics mode after installing Kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So this is exactly what I do:
Install a new VM with 8gb ram, from e.g. VMWare easy install, using file `ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`

```
apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

follow ros official install guide for Kinect, add sources, keys, run update then

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

after it installs if I reboot the os I get to the screen

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode
```

the output of dmesg gave several errors like this

```
[drm:vmw_fb_setcolreg [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Bad regno xxx
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284718/vmware-ubuntu-low-graphics-mode-after-installing-kinetic/) by [glm](https://answers.ros.org/users/34037/glm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-07**:
Welcome! Do you mean Kinetic (vs Kinect)? I'm not sure that this is a ROS issue. Please see this [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).

**Comment by [glm](https://answers.ros.org/users/34037/glm/) on 2018-03-08**:
Yes, Kinetic, sorry for this. I've been thru several of those "fixes" at Ubuntu, none of them fixed it.
It seems to be more like a VMWare issue, since I did exactly the same at a VirtualBox VPC and it worked ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reading along the web and trying other stuff I fixed it by doing

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Hope this helps someone else

---

Originally posted by [glm](https://answers.ros.org/users/34037/glm/) with karma: 16 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0